# Location of arp cache

Tags: gnome-terminal, cache, arp

I can see my arp cache if I enter `arp` into the terminal. I want to know the file location of the arp cache in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you menan /proc/net/arp ?

```
cat /proc/net/arp
```

Comment: You won't need `sudo`. Its readable for everyone.

Comment: You are right. Edited

Comment: So the full answer is: The arp cache is not a file, but sits in kermel memory. And this piece of kernel memory has a virtual file interface in the `proc` filesystem.